# Where in the filesystem is the Local History for Android Studio project files stored?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm looking for the location within the file system where the "Local History" for my project files in Android Studio is actually stored (the list you get when you right click on a particular project file and do Local History->Show History). I am wanting this for backup purposes, etc.

For reference, I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0 on Windows 8.1. I didn't see that anyone else had asked this question, and I tried to find the answer myself, but without any luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Windows, this is the default location for Local History:

> C:\Users\YourName\.AndroidStudio\system\LocalHistory

More info is on this page:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: Thanks. Is that the entire thing? It would make sense that it is, but as I indicated in my comment on the other answer, although the changes.storageData file did get updated when I made a change to one of my project files, when I searched for a string that I had added to the file it didn't come up. So I'm guessing it's either in a very compressed format, or it's not the entire thing. Do you have any further information?

Comment: I think **changes.storageData** and **changes.storageRecordIndex** files containig all your changes, but not in human readable form. Why you do not use integrated VCS inside Android Studio for this purpose?

Comment: You can use GitPortable if you don't want to install Git. And if you don't like public GitHub, you can use [free alternatives](http://toppersworld.com/top-10-free-github-alternatives-for-private-repositories/).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it this, but maybe you can find this under -

```
C:\Users\your_user_name\.AndroidStudio\system\LocalHistory
```

I hoped this could help.

Comment: Thanks, I was doing some investigating and pretty much simultaneously found that myself. The file changes.storageData did get updated when I made a change to one of my project files. However, I searched for a string that I had added and it didn't come up. So I'm guessing it's either in a very compressed format, or it's not the entire thing.

BTW, in your answer you need to add 2 backslashes before .AndroidStudio in the editor for it to display correctly.

Comment: I'm not allowed to suggest the edit since it's only 1 character, but since @EduardFlorinescu formatted that line as code, the double-backslash before .AndroidStudio that Szamot had added is now actually showing up and needs to be switched back to a single backslash.

Comment: @Xakep Fixed, thanks for bringing that up, I didn't notice that when I reviewed the edit

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is not correct for recent versions. I found it at

```
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2\LocalHistory
```